# How to use a train.csv , test.csv and ground_truth.csv in a machine learning model? (cross validation/ python)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, cross-validation

Up to now I had only one dataset (df.csv). So far I used a validation size of 20% and `.train_test_split` for a normal regression model.

```
array = df.values
X = array[:,0:26]
Y = array[:,26]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation =
   cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y,
   test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
num_folds = 10
num_instances = len(X_train)
seed = 7
scoring = 'mean_squared_error'
```

When I have three seperate datasets (train.csv/test.csv/ground_truth.csv), how can I handle it? Of course, at first I use the train.csv, then the test.csv and finally the ground_truth. But how should I implement these different datasets in my model?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, as there's no reason to push the train/test/validation splits down to csv files while training your model. I recommend reviewing the examples in sklearn's documentation and then posting a complete attempt at the regression. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: Thanks for your note. But thats exactly my problem, I know how to deal with cross validation when I have only 1 dataset. But in my case I have three datasets. train_data with run to failure events, test_data without failure events (for this I neeed the prognosis) and ground_throuth_data where the remaining live is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform cross-validation, train and test data are essentially the same dataset which is split in different ways in order to prevent overfitting. The number of folds indicates the different ways the set is split.

For example, 5-fold cross validation splits the training set in 5 pieces and each time 4 of them are used for training and 1 for testing. So in your case, you have the following options:

Either perform cross-validation just on the training set, then check with the test set and the ground truth (fitting is done just on the training set so if done correctly accuracy on test and ground truth ought to be similar) or combine training and test for a larger and possibly more representative dataset and then check on ground truth.

Comment: "Either perform cross-validation just on the training set, then check with the test set [...]" Thats the point. I'm really new in this area. How would it looks, if you have a trained model (already performed cross validation etc.) and want to test it on a second data set (test.csv)? Is there a template or a standard approach, like my code above?

Comment: Depends on the framework/algorithm that you use. From the code you posted I assume you want to use sklearn's linear regression. You can check the official documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html and search for examples. The code that you posted serves only for the split of the training set.